Alkali: if you use "washing soda" (ie baking soda heated to make it 10-times stronger base), and then dissolve it in water, does it *stay* stronger?
I really don't get how the chemistry works.
Like, I understand that the "baking soda"
(I'm not sure the term "sodium bicarbonate" is actually technically correct, so I'll just use the common term)
[EDIT: this was my first point of confusion]
has water molecules chemically bound inside its crystal structure,
[no]
and that heating it breaks those off and converts it to the anhydrous form, "washing soda"
[no]
("sodium carbonate" apparently?)
which is about 10-times stronger of a base.
(eg of claim (ie "10-times stronger"): youtube Adam Ragusea's "Ramen orecchiette — easy homemade alkaline noodle soup")
The problem is, when I go to make a noodle dough with dry "washing soda",
I find I need to add it to water and heat it first to really get it to dissolve,
which complicates the process of making a dough
(especially if you're using eggs, so you need to be careful to get it cool again before you mix those in).
So I was wondering if I could just pre-dissolve the "washing soda", and just use like a spoonfull of that in each batch of dough, except...
How does that not just convert it back into weaker "baking soda"?

EDIT:
Okay, so what thought I read about "sodium bicarbonate" being a technically incorrect misname was just completely wrong
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate#Thermal_decomposition
That is, the thermal decomposition actually is changing the molecule itself,
and not just converting the crystal structure to the anhydrous form?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate
EDIT EDIT:
I have no idea what I was thinking, where the heck I thought I read that.
maybe I was vaguely remembering that "sodium bicarbonate" (NaHCO3) doesn't actually have double the CO3, but rather, "sodium carbonate" (Na2CO3) has double the Na relative to "sodium bicarbonate"?
And I somehow got that confused into... the thing about "water of hydration/crystallization"??


Or maybe I should just find some jiǎnshuǐ(碱水 (鹼水)) / kansui(かん水) or something, i dunno...?
[which is I believe something like 80% potassium carbonate and 20% sodium carbonate dissolved in water (not sure what concentration)]

Here's a bit of experimental proof that you can convert NaHCo₃ (baking soda/sodium bicarbonate/sodium hydrogen carbonate) to Na₂Co₃ (washing soda/sodium carbonate).  It also indicates that it doesn't convert back in solution, exactly as we would expect.
Last night I put some baking soda in the oven for about an hour as it preheated to make pizza (up to 240°C).  I then made a saturated solution of the resulting sodium carbonate , and another of baking soda, by dissolving an excess in hot water an allowing it to cool.
This is where I made a slight mistake.  Baking soda starts to undergo thermal decomposition to washing soda at (per Wikipedia) 50°C.  The water I used was probably about 80°C, and the baking soda fizzed, indicating thermal decomposition.
Despite that, I still saw a difference in the solubility (qualitative, not measured, as I was aiming for saturated solutions of both). Baking soda dissolved readily leaving a small amount of residue. Sodium carbonate left more residue, forming clumps, and less dissolved in total.
The more interesting difference is in the pH.

On the left, pH about 9, we have the bicarbonate (with some contamination from the carbonate as my water was too hot) and on the right, pH about 10, the carbonate solution.
Notes:

When looking at tables of solubility, we need to consider the hydration state of the carbonate in particular - washing soda is the decahydrate, while straight out of the oven having been made from bicarb, it's presumably anhydrous.  This will affect how much we can dissolve in a given quantity of water.
pH papers are cheap - I paid £2.99 (call it $/€4) for 160 strips on eBay, and you can use half strips.  That's a lifetime's supply for the curious.


Perhaps not a full answer, but it does address some of the question directly, and needed answer formatting to include the crucial image

So cool, thanks! One thing: I'm still a bit confused about their solubilities (at 20 C)... cuz yeah, I had the same qualitative experience with the "presumably anhydrous sodium carbonate straight out of the oven" being a lot harder to dissolve, and yet the data from the tables I was able to find seem to claim the sodium carbonate is a bit above 200 g/L, while the sodium bicarbonate is lower at a bit under 100 g/L... (again, unless I just got the conversions backwards while trying to put together data from different sources).

... but like, that's grams, not... however the molarity stuff works out (washing soda basically has double the Na while only losing a single H, after all)...

But in practical kitchen terms, knowing the grams/liter solubility of washing soda at 20 C is the really useful bit, because when it comes to using it as an ingredient, keeping a bottle of it pre-dissolved at max-concentration is what you really want (since that way you can add it directly to eg egg noodle dough without needing to worry about heating it to dissolve it then cooling it not to cook the egg, and stuff like that)

Heya, I just posted a new question if you're interested: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/129042/120522

Sort of to the title. The chemistry is quite incorrect though. Washing soda stays as washing soda in water, but you can't convert baking soda (bicarbonate) into washing soda (carbonate) or vice versa easily.
Sodium carbonate (Na2CO3) and sodium bicarbonate (NaHCO3) are not hydrated/dehydrated forms of one-another. Both are crystalline substances, the carbonate one of which can contain a water of hydration/crystallization. Washing soda itself is the decahydrate (10 water molecules per molecule of carbonate) of sodium carbonate and is written as Na2CO3.10H2O. This water is incorporated into the crystal structure. Bicarbonate slowly decomposes in the presence of water to release carbon dioxide, so crystals only occur in the anhydrous form (IIRC; chemists feel free to correct me).
There are several other hydrated crystalline forms of sodium carbonate, as well as the dehydrated (anhydrous) form. You can convert the hydrated forms into the anhydrous form by heating (I think; certainly into the monohydrate), but this doesn't change the chemical properties of the carbonate.
You can convert bicarbonate into the carbonate by heating in a process called calcination, but this involves restricting the supply of oxygen, which you can't easily do at home without some specialist equipment.

Thanks, yeah, like I said in my "EDIT", I realized that what I thought I read about "sodium bicarbonate" being a technically incorrect misname was simply completely wrong. I have no idea where the heck I read that "sodium bicarbonate" was technically something more complicated... I coulda sworn I remembered that distinctly, but... I have no idea what I was thinking now. (Like, did I get it confused with some other common household chemical or something???)

... oh wait, no, maybe the fact I was remembering was that "sodium bicarbonate" doesn't actually have double the CO3, but rather, "sodium carbonate" has double the Na relative to "sodium bicarbonate"? And I somehow got that confused into... man I don't know.

@dwawlyn Yes, the bicarbonate name is a bit of a misnomer - twice as much carbonate per Na cf. Na carbonate. Yes, as I said in my answer you can thermally change the bicarbonate into the carbonate, but it requires some finesse to not overdo it and to do it properly you need to limit the O2. Much easier just to go and buy some washing soda rather than use all the electricity or gas to convert the bicarb into carb.

but... okay I don't have a pH meter in the house, but I thought "baked baking soda" (like, just heated in a pan in the oven / on the stovetop) is significantly more basic than normal baking soda? Is that not true? Or is it true but due to something other than https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate#Thermal_decomposition ?

@dwawlyn What's probably happening there is that Bicarb is hygroscopic (absorbs water from air), which decomposes it very slowly into CO2 and H2 - the exact effect that you want to get a rise in your baking. Baking/heating it will dry it out so you have more bicarb per volume and possibly convert some into carbonate. The drying out isn't necessarily removing water of hydration. I don't know if this would make it significantly more basic, but it would increase the pH a bit I think.

There are plenty of sources saying you can convert bicarbonate carbonate in a home oven (no time to find them now), and certainly doing this has the expected effect on solubility

@ChrisH good grief, my simple food question is apparently controversial basic science, ha. I guess I'm gonna have to get a pH meter if I want to satisfy at least part of my curiosity. This agrees with you?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate#Solvay_process "second step of Solvay process, heating sodium bicarbonate, used on small scale by home cooks and restaurants to make sodium carbonate for culinary purposes (including pretzels, alkali noodles). temperatures required (121 C to 149 C) to convert baking soda to sodium carbonate readily achieved in conventional kitchen ovens"

@dwawlyn also the wikipedia article on the bicarbonate talks about thermal decomposition in cooking (giving both a bit of rise and a soapy mouthfeel).  I've done a bit of experimenting with this myself: Interpreting a recipe from Mrs Beeton: "carbonate of soda"; there may be some inaccuracies in my question and the comments under it.

...I wouldn't bother with a pH meter. Having used them a couple of times in work calibration is always going to be an issue.  Universal indicator papers are cheap and should be sufficient. I may even be able to try that for you.  I have some papers and should have both time and a hot oven tomorrow. Remembering will be the hard part

@ChrisH Thanks a bunch if you can get me a point of direct-from-kitchen-data! Hm, a home pH meter was always one of those little toys I wanted to have, but you find they're too tricky to use accurately enough? btw, the solubility in water at 20 C is really { sodium bicarbonate: 96 g/L } and { sodium carbonate 2.15 g/L } ? The difference is really that big? (Like, I didn't just mess up putting together facts from different sources reported in different units or something?)

@dwawlyn more like 96 and 20 (Wikipedia, which agrees with other sources in a quick search).  But certainly measurable with 1g kitchen scales - and I have 0.1g scales.

@ChrisH Really? I found {sodium bicarbonate: 96 g/L at 20 C} from sidebar at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate, vs {sodium carbonate 21.5 g/100mL at 20 C} from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table (I think, anyway; that table page just says "units given in grams of substance per 100 millilitres of water (g/(100 mL)), unless shown otherwise", and then didn't show otherwise) -- but it does seem to agree with the data in the sidebar at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate (ie different temperatures, but all consistently fit in between)

@dwawlyn a typo in your previous comment? "sodium carbonate 2.15 g/L" (21.5 g/100ml would be 215g/l) My 20 wasn't meant to be precise.  But I also failed to spot that the Wikipedia pages for the 2 substances use different units.  Taking both from the same table avoid the confusion.

@ChrisH Oh, I accidentally shifted the wrong decimal / the wrong way, didn't I? Embarassingly durrr. So, sodium carbonate is (very roughly) twice as soluble as as sodium bicarbonate? I feel like that would slot in with my intuitive sense of "sodium carbonate is stronger", I guess? And then each ionic pair has twice the charge floating around too (right?)...
